# How to Selectively Disable Sphere Colliders?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build a pool game where the pot has a collider. Now on collision with a ball, I expect that particular ball that collided to disable.

The code below is what I've tried but it only allows me to set the ball manually. How do I automat and detect the right ball directly?

```
using UnityEngine;


using System.Collections;    
public class pot: MonoBehaviour
{   //allows me to set collider
    public SphereCollider ball;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        Debug.Log("Ball potted");
        ball = GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
        ball.enabled = !ball.enabled;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is

```
other.enabled = false;
```

what you are looking for?

Comment: Do I have to declare other, or is it inbuilt?

Comment: The "other" keyword comes from the parameter of your function.  void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your code is getting the sphere collider of the pot itself. Isn't "other" the ball in this case?

You can disable the "other" object (assuming it is the ball) with "other.gameObject.SetActive(false)" -- that's if you want the whole ball to disappear. If you just want it's collider to stop working then use "other.enabled = false".

Comment: Other refers to any other collider, is it?

Comment: Yes, that is true. Your class is called "pot", so I assumed this code was attached to the pot, and the object running into the pot (other) was the ball. If there are other things that can also hit the pot then you could tell them apart by using tags. Every ball object could be tagged "Ball" and then you could use "if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ball") { other.gameObject.SetActive(false); }"

Comment: Whoa, nice! Had no idea about other. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

```
public SphereCollider sphereCollider;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q)) //or however you want to call it.
    {
        sphereCollider = gameObject.GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
        sphereCollider.enabled = false;
    }
}
```